# trigger to only pass on real changes to the audit table

Tags: sql

I wish to only pass on changes made to ProjectID to the audit table . If for instance changes are made , but the valve stays the same , then a record is not added to the audit table .

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterUpdate ON [dbo].[Assets] 
FOR UPDATE
AS
    declare @assetid int;
    declare @assetname nvarchar(max);
    declare @projectid int;
    declare @audit_action varchar(100);

    select @assetid=i.AssetID from inserted i;  
    select @assetname=i.AssetName from inserted i;  
    select @projectid=i.ProjectID from inserted i;  

    if update(ProjectID)
        set @audit_action='Updated Record -- After Update Trigger.';

    insert into Asset_Test_Audit(AssetID,AssetName,Projectid,Audit_Action,Audit_Timestamp) 
    values(@assetid,@assetname,@projectid,@audit_action,getdate());

    PRINT 'AFTER UPDATE Trigger fired.'
GO
```

Comment: which RDBMS are you on? please add tags.

Comment: you could use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger, because MS SQL does not have `BEFORE` triggers.

Answer (score 0):

you have to compare the results from inserted table with the deleted table like below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterUpdate ON [dbo].[Assets] 
FOR UPDATE
AS
declare @assetid int;
declare @assetname nvarchar(max);
declare @projectid int;
declare @audit_action varchar(100);

select @assetid=i.AssetID from inserted i;  
select @assetname=i.AssetName from inserted i;  
select @projectid=i.ProjectID from inserted i;  

if update(ProjectID) and exists (select * from deleted 
         where AssetID<>@assetid or AssetName<>@assetname or ProjectID<>@projectid) 
begin
    set @audit_action='Updated Record -- After Update Trigger.';

insert into Asset_Test_Audit(AssetID,AssetName,Projectid,Audit_Action,Audit_Timestamp) 
values(@assetid,@assetname,@projectid,@audit_action,getdate());

PRINT 'AFTER UPDATE Trigger fired.'
end

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do it a bit differently. Inserted and deleted tables hold previous and current states of ALL records updated, and you need to audit them all:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterUpdate ON [dbo].[Assets] 
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    set NoCount ON -- So that your insert does not mess with update rowcount

    if update(ProjectID)
    begin
        insert into Asset_Test_Audit(AssetID, AssetName, Projectid, Audit_Action, Audit_Timestamp) 
        select AssetID, AssetName, ProjectID, 'Updated Record -- After Update Trigger.', getdate()
           from Inserted
           where not exists (select null from Deleted where Deleted.AssetID = Inserted.AssetID and Deleted.ProjectID = Inserted.ProjectID)
    end    
    PRINT 'AFTER UPDATE Trigger fired.'

GO
```

A few pointers: do data retrieval in one select; instead of three selects that retrieve columns from Inserted, use one:

```
select @assetid=i.AssetID, @assetname=i.AssetName, @projectid=i.ProjectID from inserted i;
```

update(ColumnName) does not imply that value of that column has changed, but merely states that it participated in update:

```
update assets set ProjectID = ProjectID
```

still returns true in *if update(ProjectID)*.

Use begin..end even when not necessary as it will save you a headache down the road. Sadly you will not know about the save, but you will certainly know (and feel the pain) if you don't.